# How to get key value pair from URL using React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactive-programming

The react-router is great when we have only one param in URL but when there are more than one params in URL, it goes wanky!!! For example, 
if the url is http://localhost:8080/foo=bar then I can get `fooValue = bar`; But if the URL is http://localhost:8080/foo=bar&this=that then I get `fooValue: "bar&this=that`".. wth!! What am I missing here?!

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Main = require('./templates/main.jsx');
var Child = require('./templates/child.jsx');

module.exports = {
  path: '/',
  component: Main,
  indexRoute: { component: Main },
  childRoutes: [
    {
        path: '/foo=:fooValue',
        component: child,
        onEnter: function (nextState) {
            console.log(nextState.params);
            //// OUTPUTS: {fooValue : "bar"}
        },
    },

    {
        path: '/foo=:fooValue&this=:thisValue',
        component: child,
        onEnter: function (nextState) {
            console.log(nextState.params);
            //// OUTPUTS: {fooValue: "bar&this=that"}

        },
    },
```

Is there a way to get key/value, `{fooValue : "bar", thisValue : "that"}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set query params in path pattern. They are passed as `location` property to components by the router, simply access them by:

```
 let { query } = this.props.location
 console.log(query);
```

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/query-params/app.js).